# Issue deleting a registry key

Tags: c#, .net, registry, registrykey

I am trying to delete a registry key, so far I tried that code which seems to be normal :

```
        RegistryKey delete = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image File Execution Options");
        delete.DeleteSubKeyTree("MyPaintApp");
        delete.Close();
```

But I get the ERROR :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I googled my problem and searched stackoverflow and applied some solutions , but all seem to be using the same method I am using, so I'm fed up and I hope you can help me with that.

EDIT : SORRY I used CurrentUser instead of LocalMachine in my registryKey path , that was the problem.

Comment: Is `delete` null? Throw in an assert, or use a debugger.

Comment: Aside from your current null exception, you should probably also use `OpenSubKey(key, true)` instead when you're modifying the key. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation of the functions you're using, before asking a question?

Comment: That key lives in HKLM, not HKCU.  Can't delete it either without asking for UAC elevation.  And can't get to it with a 32-bit program on the 64-bit version of Windows.  This key should not be messed with by a program, only humans should edit it.  It has way too many side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `OpenSubKey` states:

> Return Value
>   Type: Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
>   The subkey requested, or null if the operation failed.

Thus opening the key seems to have failed. most likely because it doesn't exist:

> If the specified subkey cannot be found, then null is returned.

On my Win7 comp, the `Image File Execution Options` subkey doesn't exist.

---

But even when you fix that part, it'll still fail. The overload of `OpenSubKey` you are using is documented as:

> Retrieves a subkey as read-only.

So you should use `OpenSubKey(path,true)`, like @lasseespeholt recommends.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(fullSubKeyPath);`.

Details here: [RegistryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3yfwzfx.aspx).